# How to extract progression from an array with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I know that one can generate an (arithmetic) progression with numpy like so:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(10, 60, 10)
array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
```

So my question is can I call something that will do the reverse ?

E.g. :

```py
>>> progression(np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]))
(10, 60, 10)
```

This is most probably not trivial, but it would be nice if there's something in numpy/scipy that can do an approximation. Also bonus points if it can recognize the type of progression without specifying.

Note: I'm aware there are similar questions already asked, but this one specifically hasn't been answered, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Since [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) works with `[start, end-step]` with a `step` size. You can infer the parameters by hand:

```
def progression(x):
    step = x[1] - x[0]
    return x[0], x[-1] + step, step
```

This of course assumes the input array follows a sequential arangement!

Comment: Correct, this will satisfy the example I gave. It won't work for anything else, however. Maybe I formulated it badly, but my question was more about advanced inputs, e.g. 1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33 has a step of n,11*n. Closest I could find is the OEIS, but that's just a database.

So I was wondering if there's something in numpy/scipy that can attempt to recognize progressions.